# How to view a PDF at its original size?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

A friend sent me a PDF with a UI mockup claiming it is 1024x768.
It is, indeed:

[image: PDF size]

However, **View > Actual Size** (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>) zooms in so much that the PDF takes up almost all 1920x1200 screen estate that is available.

How do I view the PDF at its original size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, there's a Preview preference that controls what actual size *actually* means:

[image]

If you want points to correspond directly to physical pixels, choose the first option.
(Not sure how it affects Retina displays though!)